# What's the difference between elenchus and dialectic?

Tags: plato, socrates, dialectic

I know that "elenchus" is often associated with Socrates and the Socratic method whereas "dialectic" is more associated with Plato. But what is their relationship? Is elenchus a part of dialectics? Or is elenchus basically the same as dialectics?

Comment: Elenchus is "destructive": a sort of refutation. Stating an assumption (hypothesis) and deriving absurd consequences in order to reject it.

Comment: See Jakob Fink (editor), The Development of Dialectic from Plato to Aristotle (Cambridge UP).

Comment: Consider that the etymology of "dialectic" is "dia-" for "two-of-" and "-lectic" from "lekta," which in Stoic logic were propositions (in modern parlance, the meanings of that-clauses). So "dialectic" would mean at base something like "two propositions," and as a process is the comparison and contrast of propositions as in Hegelian thesis-antithesis pairings (which linguistic imagery was inherited from Kant's discourse on antinomies as samples of "transcendental dialectic"). The elenchtic process, by comparison(!), would be specifically *erotetic*, of questions above/beyond just that-clauses.

Comment: And see G.Vlastos, *The Socratic Elenchus*, into [Socratic Studies (Cambridge UP, 1994)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Socratic_Studies/bCfaayaHBXEC), page 4: "Socratic *elenchus* is a search for moral truth by question-and-answer
adversary argument in which a thesis is debated only if asserted as
the answerer's own belief and is regarded as refuted only if its negation
is deduced from his own beliefs."

Answer (score 3):

Both technical terms are not synonyms.

Quoting from Richard Robinson [Plato’s earlier Dialectic](https://www.amazon.de/Platos-Earlier-Dialectic-Richard-Robinson/dp/019824777X):

> The
> outstanding method in Plato’s earlier dialogues is the Socratic
> elenchus. ‘Elenchus’ in the wider sense means examining a person with
> regard  to a statement he has made, by putting to him questions
> calling for further statements, in the hope that they will determine
> the meaning and the truth-value of his first statement. Most often the
> truth-value expected is falsehood; and so ‘elenchus’ in the narrower
> sense is a form of cross-examination or refutation. In this sense it
> is the most striking aspect of the behaviour of Socrates in Plato’s
> ealier dialogues. (p. 7)

> The particular method [for attaining positive doctrine, not for
> rejecting it] which Plato discusses and recommends is called by him
> ‘the dialectical method’ […] (Rp 533C) or ‘the power of conversing’
> […] (Rp. 511) or ‘the art concerning discussions’ […] (Phd. 90B) or
> the procedure of discussion’ […] (Sph. 227A).  (p. 69)

Therefore ‘elenchus’ is used by Plato as a method of refutation in his early dialogues, while ‘dialectic’ is his method to obtain a positive doctrine in his middle and late dialogues.

From the dictionary: elenchus = argument of disproof, refutation; dialectic = from the verb "dialegesthai = to parley".

Comment: Let me see if I'm understanding this correctly, the basic difference is that 'elenchus' ends up with a negative result whereas 'dialectic' ends up with a positive result? Can it also be that elenchus is a part of the dialectic?

Comment: @JohnSmith Of course Plato's method of dialectic also refutes - in the sense of elenchus - certain claims discussed in the dialogues. But dialectic does not aim at refuting all statements and to end in aporia. The aim of dialectic is to obtain true doctrines.

Comment: So elenchus ends in aporia, dialectic ends in knowledge. Is that right?

Comment: @JohnSmith Concerning elenchus I agree. Concerning dialectic: E..g., Plato's dialogue Parmenides indicates some difficulties with Plato's earlier theory of forms. Hence Plato questioned and sometimes even revised some results from his earlier work - which is not unusual for sincere academic work :-)